# Existe alguma forma no HTML de impedir que o usuário de um site utilize o zoom dos navegadores?

Tags: html

Na tag audio do html eu posso configurar o tamanho do tocador?
NO Explorer fica muito grande!

Meu problema é esse: eu gostaria que o uso do zoom in e do zoom out dos navegadores não surtisse efeito sobre uma determinada página onde só há o login pra fazer. Eu coloquei uma imagem de fundo, mas se der zoom in ou zoom out o formulário, que tem fundo transparente, vai para outra parte da imagem. Eu queria manter sempre no mesmo lugar. O background está configurado para se adaptar a qualquer tamanho de tela.

Gostaria de saber se isso é possível.

Comment: Por favor descreva melhor o seu problema e coloque HTML.

Comment: juntei à pergunta texto do seu comentário, mas ainda acho que está pouco clara para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Desculpe mas acho que você esta pensando errado. Você não pode limitar o usuário a não poder dar zoom, só porque o seu layout fica feio ou errado, você deve otimizar/corrigir o layout para que ele funcione bem em qualquer zoom, pois se for uma necessidade física do usuário ter que usar bastante zoom para poder ler? como fica?

Comment: Concordo plenamente com o @Jader

Comment: Eu não ignoro estes fatos, mas o quadro é realmente grande.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de concordar com os colegas nos comentários, algo que talvez possa ajudar é colocar no css a propriedade `background-attachment`.

```
body { 
    background-image: url('endereco-da-imagem.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Essa propriedade pode ser fixed, scroll ou local.

Você também pode fazer um background que se repita, um padrão, separando esta imagem do restante dos sprites.

Quanto ao player de audio você pode determinar a largura e altura no embed:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <embed height="50" width="100" src="horse.mp3">
</audio>
```

Novamente: os colegas estão corretos. Você não deve tirar do usuário o controle que ele tem de seu próprio navegador, mas tornar sua experiência agradável em qualquer dispostivo.